# In magento 2 how to edit the phtml file?

Tags: overrides, magento-2.0.2

In magento 2 I need to edit `topmenu.phtml` file. So I copied the `topmenu.phtml` file from:

```
vendor/magento/module_theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml
```

into:

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Theme/templates/html
```

and edited the file inside my theme module directory. But nothing changed. Someone please help me if am wrong.

> Note: I have inherited Blank theme by copying all modules from `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank` into my theme directory.

Comment: Do you copied the file on `app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Theme/template/html/` folder??

Comment: yes. I have given path fully like you said

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you paste the `topmenu.phtml` file under `app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/` folder!

Also copy the layout files which you need `app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Theme/layout` folder!

Then delete `var` folder!

Then Run `php bin/magento cache:flush` & `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` from your **root** directory!

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah I gave the path  as you mentioned above.

Comment: run the command

Comment: yes i did run the command

Comment: Now can you able to see the changes??

Comment: no. I just created a `div` to wrap all the code inside `topmenu.phtml` and gave styles for that.But am not able to see the div and its styles.

Comment: try to delete `var/view_preprocessed` folder & `pub/static/frontend` folder. Then run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Yeah I tried. Now when I change `template` to `templates` then the menus are disappearing

Comment: Are you sure that that your new theme is activated???? try to view page source and see that the from where css files are being loaded!

Comment: Yes. My css files are loading from `pub/static/frontend/<Vendor_name>/<theme_name>/en_US`

Comment: Did you copy layout folder too?? If not then copy that file and paste it also on `app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/`.Try to enable `template path hints` and see that from where your `template file is coming`

Comment: Yes.You are absolutely correct. When I copied the needed part into my xml file which is already present in that folder, It worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to community! Happy learning

Answer (score 3):

You have to set `topmenu.phtml` file inside below folder,
You have to just create `templates` folder inside it.

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml
```

Run commnad `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
clear var folder and try again.

Comment: you can set topmenu.phtml file in above location which i have mentioned and check for changes. Its working. If not changes apply plz let me know.

Comment: No the changes are not applied

Comment: have you created folder templates inside Magento_Theme, check spelling templates not only template.

Comment: If I create it as `templates` my contents are disappearing.

Comment: run command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: yes i did. Menus are getting disappeared instead of the changes being applied.

Comment: you first remove folder frontend from pub/static and run command again php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and try.