# How to Override PTHML file in magento 2

Tags: overrides

I am trying to override phtml file. for that, I have changed the path in layout for phtml and block. but my changes are not working. I have made an error in the file but nothing happens.

here is my layout file code which i am using to overriding.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="product.info.details" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product info detailed" after="product.info.media">
            <block class="XYZ\Custom\Block\Product\View\ListView" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="Custom_Module::product/view/lists.phtml"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: Please update your code

Comment: Which phtml file do you want to overide?  which theme have you using?

Comment: i am working in a custom module.

Comment: You cannot modify phtml file this way. Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111656/in-magento-2-how-to-edit-the-phtml-file

Comment: I did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To override product list.phtml file use below code

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/lists.phtml
```

and do deployment after doing this.